# Nginx redirect with and without port

Tags: nginx

we have 2 environments (test and prod) both with nginx.

To access test we use directly the host name: https://myhost:29000

To access prod we have an external LoadBalancer: https://mysite that redirects to  https://myprodhost1:29000 and  https://myprodhost2:29000

We have the following nginx configuration

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /error-page {
  port_in_redirect off;
  return 301 /;
}
```

the /error-page is handled on client side (by React), therefore it does not exists in the backend.

What we want to achieve is: if a user navigate to the error-page and press F5 it should be redirected to / (root)

The problems is that the previous configuration works for prod since the port 29000 will be omitted.
For test it is not working since we need the port:29000

I tried several configuration but I didn't succeeded.

Comment: Try: `absolute_redirect off;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just using:

```
absolute_redirect off;
```